# Connecting to Oracle 64 Bit 12c Release 12.1.0.2.0 through a C# Program Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition

Tags: c#, oracle

I am attempting to connect to an Oracle 64 Bit Release 12.1.0.2.0 Database from a c# Program created in Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition (32 Bit) Running on Windows 7 Professional OS (32 Bit).  The connection fails.  At the same time, I can connect to this Oracle Database Server through SQLPLUS with the same credentials.  I could use some help in identifying the proper ADO.NET provider for this scenario.  I have attempted this with both the Oracle.ManageddataAccess.dll and Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Comment: you are trying to connect to a 64-bit release while your OS and VS are both 32-bit. try installing the 32-bit oracle client instead. 
_P.S:_ Try lowering down the [version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-2297732.html) of oracle client and make it compatible with the workspace.

Comment: What is the error message? Please show your code.